# How to instaniate a Java Bean to hold computed values using other Beans as input

Tags: java, oop

How do you populate a Java Bean that stores values computed using input values from a number of other Java Beans, without codesmell?

I'm creating a JSF app where a user can perform an engineering calculation on a system of parts.  My facelet view has a Primefaces tabView with a tab for each part where the user enters that part's specs (material, width, thickness, diameter, etc.) and then a Results tab with a command Button which when pressed displays a number of performed engineering calculations/formulas (using MathJax) and shows their computed values.

I've coded all my input beans and started trying to populate the Results Tab but the pattern for the `computeResults()` action in my backing bean is starting to smell rotten.

Here is simplified mock code

```
@Named("calculator")
@SessionScoped    
public class BackingBean

@Inject
JointConfigurationPojo joint; //Parent POJO which groups other POJOs for Serializing just the users inputs

@Inject
JointToleranceResults jTol;  // Bean to store computed results related to joint tolerances. I'll have many more types of engineering calcs to perform

@Inject
JointTolEngServices jointTolService; // Contains engineering formulas for computing joint tolerances

public void computeResults() {
   jTol.setJoint_stackup_max(jointTolService.computeLengthMax(joint.getPlate1().getMaximum_thickness(), joint.getPlate2().getMaximum_thickness(), joint.getBoltWasher().getMaximum_thickness(), joint.getNutWasher().getMaximum_thickness());
   jTol.setJoint_stackup_min(jointTolService.computeLengthMin(joint.getPlate1().getMinimum_thickness(), joint.getPlate2().getMinimum_thickness(), joint.getBoltWasher().getMinimum_thickness(), joint.getNutWasher().getMinimum_thickness());
   jTol.setMin_bolt_thread(jointTolService.computeThreadProtrusion(joint.getPlate1().getMinimum_thickness(), joint.getPlate2().getMinimum_thickness(), joint.getBoltWasher().getMinimum_thickness(), joint.getNutWasher().getMinimum_thickness(), joint.getBolt().getBoltShaftLength(), joint.getNut().getNutHeight());
yuk or is this how it's got to be??
}
```

I have a dozen or more computation results beans and this section is getting messy. How do I clean up the computeResults() method?? There has to be a better way to instantiate all of the results beans.  ...with constructors? CDI?

--

```
Bolt Input Tab/Form:
    <p:inputText size="1" id="bolt_length" value="#{jointCalc.joint.bolt.nominal_fastener_length}">
```

--

```
Results Tab
#{jointCalc.jTol.joint_stackup_max} 
#{jointCalc.jTol.joint_stackup_min} 
#{jointCalc.jTol.min_bolt_thread} 
etc...
```

--

```
public class JointConfigurationPojo implements Serializable { //Could have various number of joint configurations (Tapped hole/weld stud/3plates)
  public JointConfigurationPojo () {
    bolt = new Bolt();
    boltWasher = new Washer();
    nutWasher = new Washer();
    nut = new Nut();
    plate1 = new Plate();
    plate2 = new Plate();
}
```

Comment: Admittedly not pretty, but besides your methods taking a decent amount of parameters, I don't see anything wrong with what you're doing.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with which is better, to pass individual parameters, or my whole jointConfiguration bean .... jointTolService.computeLengthMax(joint), or even jointTolService.computeLengthMax(joint.getPlate1(), joint.getPlate2(), etc.. then grab the plates two thickness attributes.

Comment: I don't see that this question is unique to JSF. It's just a [refactoring](http://martinfowler.com/books/refactoring.html) problem. You may encounter some technical difficulties when trying to implement certain refactorings in JSF, but you can ask a more specific question if that happens.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should let your beans do more work on computation, if it's not possible then you can pass the whole bean to `jointTolService`.

And it should be like that:

```
jointTolService.computeLengthMax(joint);
jointTolService.computeLengthMin(joint);
jointTolService.computeThreadProtrusion(joint)
```

Or better

```
 jointTolService.setJoint(joint);
 JointToleranceResults result = jointTolService.makeAllCalculation();
```

and  `jointTolService.makeAllCalculation()` would call the compute methods.